# glDrawElements draw polygon

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, polygon

I have read that the first parameter of the glDrawElements is mode:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml

> Symbolic constants GL_POINTS, GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_LINES, GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY, GL_LINES_ADJACENCY, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY and GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY are accepted.

I do not see there GL_POLYGON. Is that means that I can not use GL_POLYGON? and if I got 10 indices? Am I need to transform it to a few polygons which contains 3 indices each one? If it is true, How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GL3](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/) and [GL4](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) level man pages on www.opengl.org only document the Core Profile of OpenGL. `GL_POLYGON` is deprecated, and was not part of the Core Profile when the spec was split into Core and Compatibility profiles in OpenGL 3.2.

You can still use `GL_POLYGON` if you create a context that supports the Compatibility Profile. But if you start out, I would suggest that you stick to Core Profile features. If you do need documentation for the deprecated features, you'll have to go back to the [GL2 man pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/).

To draw a polygon, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` is the easiest replacement. You can use the same set of vertices for a triangle fan as you would use for `GL_POLYGON`, and it will produce the same result.

Comment: Why `GL_POLYGON` is deprecated? I have checked with `GL_POLYGON` and with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN ` and the FPS stays the same.

Comment: Both `GL_POLYGON` and `GL_QUADS` have been removed. Polygons and quads opens a bunch of problem (what if you submit a non-planar polygon? what if your polygon is not convex? how do you interpolate values between a polygon vertices? how do you clip them?). Just triangulate your faces yourself and submit triangles. There are libraries for this use.

Comment: What is the names of these libraries?

Comment: Those are not the latest manual pages as you claim, by the way. Those are the GL3 manual pages. You can tell this because the [*latest*](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) manual pages are GL4, which includes `GL_PATCHES` as a primitive type for tessellation shaders.

Comment: Sorry about the "latest" wording in the original answer, which was ambiguous at best. I fixed the answer to be more precise. I always considered 3.2 to be the first version with a core profile, because that's the first version where I see separate spec documents.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to the GL3 manual pages, by the way.

Since `GL_POLYGON` was deprecated in 3.0 and removed in 3.1, you are not going to find it listed there. In fact, you will find some tokens there that are only supported in GL 3.2 (adjacency primitives, which were introduced when Geometry Shaders were); fortunately ***that*** is actually documented in the manual page itself unlike the fact that `GL_POLYGON` was deprecated.

For compatibility profiles (which you are using), you should view the GL2 manual page. The GL2 man page can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml).